# Junit test cases List

Tags: java, unit-testing, arraylist, junit, tdd

Trying to make sure I understand the JUnit and TDD.

The first test is to test if the basket is empty before adding any content.

```
@Test
public void test_GetBooksInBasket_ReturnEmptyBookList_IfNoBooksHaveBeenAdded(){
    //Arrange
    Basket basket = new Basket();

    //Act
     List<Object> test = basket.getBooksInBasket();


    //Assert
    assertThat(test.size(),is(1));

    System.out.println(test.size());

}
```

The class

```
public class Book {

}


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Basket {

private List<Object> bookList = new ArrayList<Object>();

public List<Object> getBooksInBasket(){

    return bookList;
  }

}
```

Just wanted to know if i did the first test case right. I got failure when i tested for 1 since the list was empty.

Test 2. Same code as above but add a book to basket and check if the number of books in basket is equal to 1.

```
public void test_GetBooksInBasket_ReturnsArrayOfLengthOne_After_AddBookMethodIsCalledWithOneBook(){
    //Arrange
    Basket basket = new Basket();
    Book book = new Book();

    //Act
List<Object> test = basket.addBook(book);


    //Assert
assertThat(test.size(),is(0));
}
public class Basket {

private List<Object> bookList = new ArrayList<Object>();

public List<Object> getBooksInBasket(){

    return bookList;
}

public  List<Object> addBook(Book book){
    Book book1 = new Book();
    //Book book3 = new Book();
    bookList.add(book1);
    return bookList;



}


}
```

Not getting any failures for this no matter was size i put in.

Test 3 is adding 2 books so i tried this

```
public void test_GetBooksInBasket_ReturnsArrayOfLengthOne_After_AddBookMethodIsCalledWithOneBook(){
    //Arrange
    Basket basket = new Basket();
    Book book = new Book();

    //Act
List<Object> test = basket.addBook(book,book);


    //Assert
assertThat(test.size(),is(0));
}



public  List<Object> addBook(Book book, Book book1){
    Book book2 = new Book();
    Book book3 = new Book();
    bookList.addAll(Arrays.asList(book2, book3));
    return bookList;

    }
```

Not sure if my second and third test cases are working correctly.

Comment: You should assert the expected value against the actual value. If you expect an empty `List` then perform the assertion like this: `assertEquals(0 /* expected */, list.size() /* actual */)`.

Comment: @trylimits alright thanks, i switched for my first test case and it works. Do you know what i should do for the other two?

Comment: Do the same thing: assert against the expected value. After you have added a single book, you would expect the basket to contain exactly one book. So assert like this: `assertEquals(1 /* expected */, list.size())`.

Comment: @trylimits problem is ill try that and if i put 0  1 or 2 it will still come out true

Answer (score 0):

Your tested class has no behavior of its own. It just delegates the calls to its methods to its internal data structure. Overmore it violates the most important OO principle (information hiding/encapsulation).

Because of this your code verifies the *state* of the tested class.
But Unittests should verify *behavior* which is *return values* and/or *communication with dependencies*.

Problem here is that your code under test needs some genuine behavior to test.

IMHO your class `Basked` should do more than "holding items" (which you could achieve by using the `ArrayList` directly. Maybe your `Basket` has a limit of items. Then you could verify some behavior this way:

```
class BasketWithLimitTest{

  private static final int BASKET_CONTENT_LIMIT = 2;
  @Rule
  public MockitoRule rule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

  @Rule
  public final ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

  @Mock(name="Book1");
  private book1;
  @Mock(name="Book2");
  private book2;
  @Mock(name="Book3");
  private book3;

  @Test
  public void isInitiallyEmpty(){
     Basket basket new Basket(BASKET_CONTENT_LIMIT);

     basket.add(book1);

     assertThat("not empty", basket.isEmpty(),is(true));
     assertThat("not containing the book1", basket.contains(book1),is(false));
     assertThat("not containing the book2", basket.contains(book2),is(false));
  }
  @Test
  public void firtsBookStoredSuccessfully(){
     Basket basket new Basket(BASKET_CONTENT_LIMIT);

     basket.add(book1);

     assertThat("not empty", basket.isEmpty(),is(false));
     assertThat("contains the book", basket.contains(book1),is(true));
  }
  @Test
  public void throwExceptionWhenLimitExceeded(){
     Basket basket new Basket(BASKET_CONTENT_LIMIT);

     basket.add(book1);
     basket.add(book2);

     exception.expect(RuntimeException.class);
     exception.expectMessage("could not add Book3 because limit of 2 books exceeded");
     basket.add(book3);

  }
}
```